# Trying to get my discord bot in python to say the same message every 5 seconds

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making sort of a "hack" for dank memer. I have made my own bot. My goal with the bot was to get it to keep saying "pls search" about every 5 seconds. Eventually, I would make a command that says "pls give 100" to get the coins. Instead of showing up in discord, it showed up in my app.

```
@client.command()
async def go(ctx):
    def printit():
        threading.Timer(5.0, printit).start()
        await ctx.send("pls search")
    printit()
```

Answer (score 1):

This will continuously send messages, but you will get rate-limited. This works by scheduling a task in the event loop that sends messages, then canceling it.

```
import asyncio

@bot.command()
async def comm(ctx):
    async def f():
        while True:
            # await asyncio.sleep(.5)  # Control message speed
            await ctx.send('Test')
    await ctx.send("Start")
    task = asyncio.create_task(f())
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await ctx.send("End")
    task.cancel()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
import time    
@bot.command()
    async def start(ctx, number_of_times=5):
       for i in range(number_of_times):
           await ctx.send('pls search')
           time.sleep(5)
       # type in the user
       await ctx.send('pls give <user> 100')
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import discord, os, asyncio

from discord.ext import commands

from colorama import Fore, Style

token = "Token Here"

#Bot prefix, like ?help

prefix = ["|", "!", "/"]


def endSong(guild, path):

    os.remove(path)


#Clear Command


def Clear():

    os.system('clear')


#Colors


def RandomColor():

    randcolor = discord.Color(random.randint(0x000000, 0xFFFFFF))

    return randcolor


def RandString():

    return "".join(
        random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits)
        for i in range(random.randint(14, 32)))


#Prefix

client = discord.Client()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, self_bot=True)

#Dep


@client.command(name='dankmemer', aliases=['dank', 'dmc'])
async def dankmemer(ctx):

    await ctx.message.delete()

    count = 0

    while True:

        try:

            count += 1

            await ctx.send('pls beg')

            print(
                f'{Fore.BLUE}[AUTO-MEME] {Fore.GREEN}Meme number: {count} sent'
                + Fore.RESET)

            await asyncio.sleep(26)

        except Exception as e:

            print(f"{Fore.RED}[ERROR]: {Fore.YELLOW}{e}" + Fore.RESET)


#Farm


@client.command(name='dank-farm', aliases=['dankfarm', "dm"])
async def _fish_dank(ctx):  # b'\xfc'

    await ctx.message.delete()

    count = 0

    while True:

        try:

            count += 1

            await ctx.send('pls fish')

            await ctx.send('pls hunt')

            await ctx.send('pls dig')

            print(
                f'{Fore.BLUE}[AUTO-FARM] {Fore.GREEN}Farm number: {count} sent'
                + Fore.RESET)

            await asyncio.sleep(26)

        except Exception as e:

            print(f"{Fore.RED}[ERROR]: {Fore.YELLOW}{e}" + Fore.RESET)


#onReady


@client.event
async def on_ready():

    print(f"You are Online :)")


client.run(token, bot=False)
```

Comment: This is just an old dank memer farmer I made. U will probably have to update it.